# Android parse -how to grant a user premission to edit another user's details?

Tags: android, parse-platform, admin

I am working with parse on Android Studio, creating some sort of a "Library" app. Basically , I have User (_User) class on my parse , and I want to be able to change user's detail while logged in as another user.
Let's say - I'm logged in as a "Librarian" - which is a regular user that has a boolean variable called "librarian" (a "librarian" column on parse) . Logging in as a user with "Librarian" set as "True" brings me to a special menu, from which I want to edit another user - a regular user's ("librarian"=false) details, such as "Address", "Age" etc. For some reason I can't , and I believe it has to do with ACL settings or something.
I have tried to read the "Roles" doc on parse yet I still don't understand.

So to sum up -
I want to edit a user while logged in as a another , more "powerful" user.
If you guys think I should use roles , please let me know how.

Thank you ,
Idan.

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: @Apurva if you meant to edit the title , I did. If not , please explain.